Mulesoft CassandraDB Module 4.1.2 and Connection Pooling Configuration?
All documentation I see does not mention connection pooling configuration. When I configure the connection in Anypoint studio there are not options. I saw the old mule module mentions pooling options in the global config. But with the new one no mention and no options. I also saw the new datastax driver used also changed pooling and uses configuration options. So I'm not sure how to get this to work and setup in mule.
Does anyone know how to configure connection pooling in mule for CassandraDB Module 4.1.2?

Could you post the link for the old module where it talks about pooling options?

Do you mean the Mule 3 connector configuration had a pooling option? The Mule 4 connector is a different implementation.

@ErickRamirez https://docs.mulesoft.com/cassandra-connector/0.3.9/cassandra-connector-install-conf-task Optionally, click Pooling Profile. Configure any settings relevant to managing multiple connections using a connection pool.

@aled I think so. The 3.9 Cassandra Connector that was for Mule 3 mentioned pooling profile. The new Cassandra Connector for Mule 4 I have not found any mention or instructions on how to setup or configure in Mule4. I've never used Mule 3 and only just started to work with Mule 4. So my experience is limited.
